# How to remove rows which has same values in variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

How to remove rows which has identical string variable?
Here is example data:

```
data <- data.frame(c("A", "C", "B"),
                     c("A", "B", "C"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(data)
#   c..A....C....B.. c..A....B....C..
#1                A                A
#2                C                B
#3                B                C
```

For the output I would like to get this dataframe:

```
#  c..A....C....B.. c..A....B....C..
#2                C                B
#3                B                C
```

As you can see in the first row, same A and A are deleted.
tidyverse approach preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data <- data.frame(x = c("A", "C", "B"),
                   y = c("A", "B", "C"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  filter(x != y)

  x y
1 C B
2 B C
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(data, x != y)
```